# Mathjax fonts ttf file download link needed

Tags: support, mathjax, font

Long time ago, I was a regular attendee of math.stackexchange and then probably from the meta site, I found a web link (probably github link) to lots of mathjax fonts '.ttf' files for my pc. Those fonts were much helpful while math typesetting in Ms-word etc. for simple documentations.

But, today, I searched web for the .ttf file mathjax font like Mathjax_Math, Mathjax_Main, Mathjax_AMS, Mathjax_Caligraphic etc, but cannot find that webpage link anywhere. Also I have deleted my stackexchange a/c long ago, so, can't run the search through the site thoroughly!

Someone please post the link of all those mathjax fonts for pc. Thanks.

Comment: See [MathJax font support](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output/fonts.html) for information about the latest version, which likely differs from what you recall.  I'm not sure you are asking about how MathJax works on this site, so if you are concerned with typesetting math "in Ms-word etc.", the request may not be on-topic.

Comment: This sounds like a question about mathjax, and not math.stackexchange (or indeed any stackexchange site). Is this right?

Comment: Maybe XITS https://github.com/alif-type/xits ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MathJax moved from ttf versions of the fonts some time ago, and now uses woff versions (or otf for very old browsers).  You can find the fonts used for v2 (which is what is in use at StackExchange) [here](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/tree/legacy-v2/fonts/HTML-CSS).  You probably want either the STIX fonts or the TeX fonts, and should be able to install either the otf or woff versions locally on your PC.